# Pattern for a class to return different methods based on options?

Tags: python, oop

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,opt):
        if not hasattr(self,opt):
            raise SystemExit(1)
        getattr(self,opt)()

    def optionA(self):
        return "A"

    def optionB(self):
        return "B"
```

Now, when I try to use it

```
>> A('optionA')
<__main__.A instance at 0x7f87bccfca70>
```

what I want it to return is "A". So I tried using

```
class A:
    def __call__(self,opt):
        if not hasattr(self,opt):
            raise SystemExit(1)
        getattr(self,opt)()

    def optionA(self):
        return "A"

    def optionB(self):
        return "B"
```

This works but now I have to make this ugly call

```
A()("optionA")
```

Comment: the '__init__' method of any class wont return a value, and any return value from it is thrown away.

Comment: How are you going to assign the instance to variable if you want to return "A" on class instantiation?

Comment: Not sure to really understand your question, but the special method `__new__` returns an object instead of configuring a just created one as `__init__` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problem are you trying to solve with this? Are you just using the class as a function container? You could try the below; it's a bit prettier.

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def optionA():
        return "A"

    @staticmethod
    def optionB():
        return "B"

    @staticmethod
    def run(opt):
        if not hasattr(A, opt):
            raise SystemExit(1)
        else:
            f = getattr(A, opt)
            return f()

print A.run('optionA')
```

Answer (score 1):

`init` method don't return a value, if you want to make it work do this,
use another isntance method `getdata`(in my case):-

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,opt):
        self.opt = opt           # initialize the argument
        if not hasattr(self,opt):
            raise SystemExit(1)
    def getdata(self):
        return getattr(self, self.opt)() #`self.opt` use the argument 

    def optionA(self):
        return "A"

    def optionB(self):
        return "B"
a = A('optionA')
c = a.getdata()
print c
```